# How to clear spinner listener

Tags: android, spinner

I am very new to android.I have set spinner SetOnItemSelected Listener.  Is there any possibilities to cancel spinner OnItemSelectedListener from another method. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `setOnItemSelectedListener(null)` to remove an `OnItemSelectedListener`.

Comment: I have had a very annoying bug in my app for months now and I'm hoping that turning my Spinner listeners on and off at the proper times will fix it.  I would have never thought to do this, but it popped up in my keyword search.